# Writing tests for script files in F#

Tags: f#, tdd, xunit

I have some functionality withing a script file, setup.fsx
I would like to test those.
xUnit and the likes needs the functions to be tested to be part of the assembly.

So I am thinking of renaming my script from setup.fsx to setup.fs extension, then loading it from another script file. But then my script depends on

```
#r "System.Xml"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
```

which I would then have to specify in the calling script (away from where the dependency actually arises)

Are there anyway to integrate tests based on scripts in the xUnit worflow ? 
What organization is suggested for writing tests for script files ?

(may be we need a visual studio extension for tests in scripts and not in assembly..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you just add `fsx` script to Visual Studio, you can still compile `setup.fsx` into a normal project together with other (possibly `fs`) files, so you should be able to keep the script as a normal script file in Visual Studio and, at the same time, reference it from a project or from a command line tool that builds your tests.

I tried doing that with the following `test.fsx` file:

```
module Demo
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open System.Xml.Linq

let test () = 
    let d = XDocument(XElement(XName.Get("foo")))
    d.ToString()
```

You definitely need some `module Name` declaration at the beginning (so that you can access functions from other files), but otherwise it can be any `fsx` file. The other file that I used was `test.fs`:

```
module Main
open Demo    
test() |> printfn "%A"
```

This is just for testing, but here you could write your unit tests. If you compile the files with the following command, you get standard assembly that you could pass to xUnit (note, the compiler can pick the `#r` tag from `test.fsx`, we do not have to write the reference explicitly):

```
fsc.exe --target:library test.fsx test.fs
```

I think you could get the same configuration in Visual Studio if you add a library project and then manually add link to the file (which can point to a file elsewhere in your solution structure) using something like this in the `fsproj` file:

```
<Compile Include="..\Eslewhere\In\Your\Project\Tree\File.fsx">
  <Link>File.fsx</Link>
</Compile>
```

Note that when you add `fsx` file using "Add Item", it is marked as "Include" but not as "Compile", so it does not get compiled as part of the project. The above should include it in the project and it should tell the compiler to include it in the compiled assembly too.

**Warning:** that said, I think it might be better to test just compiled `dll` files using standard unit tests. If you want to test `fsx` files, I would just add a couple of lines as tests at the end and run them by hand (select, `Alt`+`Enter`). The reason is that `fsx` files are supposed to be changed quite often and so having too solid testing may limit your flexibility. On the other hand, once code gets more solid, it makes sense to move it to a `dll` file.

Comment: if you write module on top in the fsx, you can't execute it in fsi.   adding #if COMPILED
module Demo
#endif
seems ok

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the Demo namespace when it is defined in a fsx file ? I get an error. the fsx file is above in the project list.. the error disappear upon renaming to fs, appears switching back to fsx

Comment: @nicolas I only tried to run the compiler by hand from command line. I think it will only work if the `fsx` file is marked as Compile - what is the command line command that Visual Studio prints in the "Output" window? Can you see the `fsx` file therE?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to take the code you want to have tested and put it in a separate `*.fs` file. In your `*.fsx` script, you can use the `#load` directive to load the code from the `*.fs` file (`#load` works like `#include` in C/C++).

For unit testing, you can create a simple F# library project which includes the `*.fs` file using `<Link>` (as in Tomas' answer), then run your unit tests against the compiled DLL.